# Set option classes from array of data

Tags: jquery, arrays, html-select

I have two dropdown menus (state and county) that control the display of divs containing city info. The county menu generates options for all the city divs, but the duplicate options are filtered out on document ready. That aspect works fine, as shown in the jsfiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ph68fxya/

What doesn't completely work is hiding the county options that are irrelevant when a particular state is selected. I have a function for that which I've included after, but it won't work until I can figure out how to set the classes with stateValues in the county menu options. I know I have to loop through, but I can't figure out how to do that. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var stateValues = [];
var countyValues = [];
$("div.city").each(function (index, elem) {
    stateValues.push($(this).data("state"));
    countyValues.push($(this).data("county"));
});
var uniqueValues = [];
$(countyValues).each(function (index, item) {
    if ($.inArray(item, uniqueValues) == -1) uniqueValues.push(item);
});
$(uniqueValues).each(function (index, item) {
    $("#county").append($("<option class='"+stateValues+"'>").html(item));
});
});
```

Here is the additional function, which should work once the option classes are defined:

```
$.conditionalize = function(state,county){
var counties = view.children().clone();    
state.change(function(){
    var chooseState = $(this).val();                  
    view.children.not((".chooseState")).remove();
    counties.clone().filter("."+counties).appendTo(county);
}).trigger("change");
}
$.conditionalize($("#state"),$("#county"));
```

Comment: do you want to filter the county dropdown based on the state ?

Comment: Yes. In the bottom function, it's removing options whose class does not match the selected state. stateValues up top and chooseState on the bottom will end up being the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This would filter your county based on the state.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var stateValues = [];
        var countyValues = [];
        var countyState = {};
        $("div.city").each(function (index, elem) {
            stateValues.push($(this).data("state"));
            countyValues.push($(this).data("county"));
            countyState[$(this).data("county")] = $(this).data("state");
        });
        var uniqueValues = [];
        $(countyValues).each(function (index, item) {
            if ($.inArray(item, uniqueValues) == -1) uniqueValues.push(item);
        });
        $(uniqueValues).each(function (index, item) {
            $("#county").append($("<option class='" + countyState[item] + "'>").html(item));
        });

        $("#state").change(function()
        {
            var val = $(this).val();
            $("#county option").each(function()
            {
               if($(this).attr("class") != val)
                   $(this).hide();
                else
                    $(this).show();
            });            
        });


    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ph68fxya/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot, DinoMyte. That's just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this to set the classes. Track which county belongs to which state with an object. Then when you are creating the options for the county select field find what state the option belongs to using the object.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ph68fxya/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var stateValues = [];
    var countyValues = [];
    // Initialize object
    var countyState = {};
    $("div.city").each(function (index, elem) {
        stateValues.push($(this).data("state"));
        countyValues.push($(this).data("county"));
        // For each county add its state to object
        countyState[$(this).data("county")] = $(this).data("state");
    });
    var uniqueValues = [];
    $(countyValues).each(function (index, item) {
        if ($.inArray(item, uniqueValues) == -1) uniqueValues.push(item);
    });
    $(uniqueValues).each(function (index, item) {
        // As you create county option find its state in object
        $("#county").append($("<option class='" + countyState[item] + "'>").html(item));
    });
});
```